# Elasticsearch boost score by token position in graph

Tags: elasticsearch

Question is similar to [Elasticsearch token position relevance to scoring?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45162643/elasticsearch-token-position-relevance-to-scoring) (this question is old and there is no answer), also I need to define own boost value for each token by position.

For example, I have 2 documents

```
{
  "f": "orange apple tomato"
},
{
  "f": "apple orage tomato"
}
```

And I want to score these values like `f[0]^300, f[1]^150, f[2]^75`

and if I search `apple` first document should have score 300, and second 150.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking for `Scoring by term position in ElasticSearch` Check this one

[image]

[Scoring by term position in ElasticSearch?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27538766/scoring-by-term-position-in-elasticsearch)